# Is it possible to upload files from FTP to FTP using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Here is my prob in Brief.

I know how to upload a file to server using FTP with programming language PHP.

But is that possible to get files from another server to our server using PHP with

having the FTP Username and Password

Thanks n advance...

Fero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch files from FTP using PHP - using [`ftp_get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php).

The following snippet is from the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php):

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the FTP protocol allows for server-to-server transfers, called [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol).  This feature is disabled by default on most FTP servers, though, for security reasons, so you would need to be able to verify/enable it before it would work.

If it is enabled, you should just need to script the [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) commands and everything should work fine.

Comment: hi starbuck.. I don't want to use FTP features. i need to use with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a promising function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php

You'll need to open the local file up for dumping into, and manage the connection and whatnot, but this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's much different from copying a file from a directory to another, provided that you know how to *open* a file in an FTP Server..